# How to login to VisualSVN Server (with Single Sign-On enabled) under other user than the currently logged one to Windows machine?

Tags: active-directory, svn, windows-authentication, single-sign-on, visualsvn-server

If you have Integrated Windows Authentication as the only authentication type enabled in VisualSVN Server you don't get any login / password prompts.

You may find yourself stuck and confused if sometimes you should access VisualSVN Server under other users' account than the one you are currently logged-on.

*Is there any convenient workaround?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Windows Credential Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/What-is-Credential-Manager) to store the other account's credentials for Single Sign-On.

The following instruction shows how to put other domain credentials to access VisualSVN Server into Windows Credential Manager:

1. **Start | Control Panel | Credential Manager**,
2. Click *'Add a Windows Credential'*,
3. As *'Internet or network address'* enter the FQDN of VisualSVN
   Server's machine,
4. As *'Username'* enter the `<DOMAIN>\<username>` of user account that
   exists in domain and has access rights to VisualSVN Server,
5. Complete the password field and click OK,
6. Verify that you can authenticate to VisualSVN Server under the selected user account after completing the above steps.